# Prevent Mongoose from duplicating save

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So we're not sure why it sometimes does this and other times it works fine.

but we have a function that checks saves the following:

```js
var Insert = new NowPlaying({
    "type": "A",
    "station": req.params.stationname,
    "cover": addocs[0].match.banner[0],
    "url": addocs[0].match.url,
    "song": addocs[0].match.title,
    "artist": addocs[0].match.campaignName,
    "timeplay": npdate,
    "campaignID": addocs[0].match._id,
    "areaID": addocs[0].areaID,
    history: [uuid]
});

Insert.save(function (err, book) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(book.name + " saved.");
});
```

However sometimes it saves the same data multiple times, I am wondering how do I make sure it only runs once.

```js
var aquery = Adverts.aggregate(advertquery);

aquery.exec(function (err, addocs) {
    // console.error(addocs[0]);
    
    if (addocs[0]) {
        // remote = "https://storage.googleapis.com/ad-system/testfolder/OUTOFAREA.mp3";  
        remote = addocs[0].match.audio;

        /* add to now playing  */
        let date_ob = new Date();
        let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
        let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
        let hours =  ("0" + (date_ob.getHours() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let minutes = ("0" + (date_ob.getMinutes() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let seconds = ("0" + (date_ob.getSeconds() + 1)).slice(-2);
        
        var npdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + date + "T" + hours + ":" + minutes +":"+ seconds;

        const query = {
            "type": "A",
            "station": req.params.stationname,
            "cover": addocs[0].match.banner[0],
            "url": addocs[0].match.url,
            "song": addocs[0].match.title,
            "artist": addocs[0].match.campaignName,
            "timeplay": npdate,
            "campaignID": addocs[0].match._id,
            "areaID": addocs[0].areaID,
            history: [uuid]
        };
        
        console.log(uuid+" is PLAYING"+ JSON.stringify(query))

        var Insert = new NowPlaying({
            "type": "A",
            "station": req.params.stationname,
            "cover": addocs[0].match.banner[0],
            "url": addocs[0].match.url,
            "song": addocs[0].match.title,
            "artist": addocs[0].match.campaignName,
            "timeplay": npdate,
            "campaignID": addocs[0].match._id,
            "areaID": addocs[0].areaID,
            history: [uuid]
        });
        
        Insert.save(function (err, book) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(book.name + " saved.");
        });
        
        /* end now playing */
    }
})

// CODE REMOVED AS NOT NEEDED FOR QUESTION
```

Comment: _"However sometimes it saves the same data multiple times"_. Perhaps because it gets called multiple times?

Comment: @robertklep it only seems to happen when a user is on Desktop (safari, chrome, windows explorer) - when they use the platform by iOS or Android it works fine.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on how your code gets called exactly.

Comment: @robertklep the easy solution is to do an update and upsert it if it does not exist.
Meaning as long as the query and the update query is the same then it should if not found just update, if it is found replace? - I am sure not best practice but it would work.

If only .save() could make sure it was not duplicating a record.

Comment: You can use a unique index to prevent duplicate records, or (as you suggest) using upserts, but in the end, the issue is with `.save()` getting called multiple times from somewhere in your code. If you call it from, say, some HTTP request handler, one thing to consider is that it may be getting called for "implicit" requests like one for `/favicon.ico` (always a favorite to cause unexpected requests).